# docker OCI runtime create failed

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm using a following docker-compose file in a java web app project.

```
version: "3"
services:
  product:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - Product/target/Product.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments
```

The error I'm getting is

```
ERROR: Named volume "Product/target/Product.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments:rw" is used in service "product" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose.yml': `docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

---

**Edit** **OCI runtime create failed:**

Following the fix of the path, I'm encountering another error. OCI runtime create failed:

```
Deploying 'Compose: docker-compose.yml'...
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /Users/username/Desktop/Project/docker-compose.yml up -d
Starting project_product ... 
Starting project_product ... error
ERROR: for project_product  Cannot start service product: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/username/Desktop/Project/User/target/Product.war\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e090197e0697ec14446020cf2444dc0d3f39dfb240de9f399017415f6faeb13b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e090197e0697ec14446020cf2444dc0d3f39dfb240de9f399017415f6faeb13b/merged/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for product  Cannot start service product: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/username/Desktop/Project/User/target/Product.war\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e090197e0697ec14446020cf2444dc0d3f39dfb240de9f399017415f6faeb13b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e090197e0697ec14446020cf2444dc0d3f39dfb240de9f399017415f6faeb13b/merged/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose.yml': `docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `./Product/target...`

Comment: Docker compile file volume mounts have to be absolute paths. You can use ${PWD} to specify your current directory.

Comment: Thanks guys, it fixed but encountering another error, please see the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `.` at the beginning or use an absolute path when mounting a local file into a container. Otherwise Docker will assume it's a named volume, as the error suggests.

Comment: it works fine without volume property in the yml file

Comment: fixed. appended product.war to the  target volume